# How many file descriptors are open?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, file-descriptor, resource-leak

I have a server using libzmq that leaks filedescriptors under certain conditions. The problem seems to be a race condition inside libzmq and is hard to debug and is not going to get solved anytime soon. So please don't recommend fixing it. That's a long term solution and I need a quick fix. So the plan is now to restart the server whenever it accumulates ~500 FDs.

The question now is: How many file descriptors are open? What's a good way of counting them with python3 under Linux?

What I have tried is stating "/proc/self/fd" and checking the link count. But that's always 2. Now I open and readdir "/proc/self/fd" and count entries. But that just seems rather ineffiecient.

Are there any other / better solutions?

Update: In case it wasn't clear, the server is written in python3 and the plan is for the server itself to check the descriptor count and if it has too many leaked FDs it shall restart itself (at a suitable time where it doesn't cause problems) before it runs out of FDs and causes failures.

I don't want some external monitor or something that kills the server when it leaks. The server is well aware of the problem and shall deal with it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir` :

```
# Create 1000 temporary files, and count netries in /proc/self/fd
import tempfile
from timeit import default_timer as timer
array = [tempfile.TemporaryFile('w') for _ in range(1000)]
start=timer()
sum(1 for _ in os.listdir('/proc/self/fd'))
print(timer() - start)
# output : 0.001 seconds
```

Not sure if can be considered `rather ineffiecient`

Comment: If you're going to use `os.listdir`, you can just do `len(os.listdir('/proc/self/fd'))` and save the genexpr and `sum` (`list`s already know their own length). The loop might make sense for `sum(1 for _ in os.scandir('/proc/self/fd'))` which would at least avoid constructing the whole `list` of entries in memory (that said, the `list` of open file descriptors should be small enough not to matter either way).

Comment: I basically had `sum(1 for _ in os.scandir('/proc/self/fd'))` but `len(os.listdir('/proc/self/fd'))` I think looks nicer. Might also use the readdir2 syscall to read multiple entries at a time instead of one readdir call per `scandir`.

Answer (score 0):

You should count fd's in /proc/"server process number"/fd instead of /proc/self/fd

Comment: It's the server counting it's own FDs. /proc/self is a link to it's own pid. Means I can use a static string instead of dynamically build the path with the pid in it.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow *"But that's always 2."* This shows clearly that you are not counting from the correct process. Maybe your server spawns other processes or threads and the leak happens in a subprocess? Or maybe your count itself is run from a subprocess? Did you look directly (manually from command prompt) at /proc/theServerProcess/fd to assess that the leak is from that process? AFAIKT your method should work.

Comment: @J-p-tosoni The link count of the "fd" directory is always 2 regardless of how many open filedescriptors are actually in that directoy.

Comment: OK. I thought you were counting the files, not the links. The number of links is not the info you want (it is the number of subdirectories + 2). You have not other way but to count the number of files in fd/ one by one (and subtract 2 for . and ..). So, the answer from Philippe which uses os.listdir is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing nothing about your server processes' architecture I'd suggest a name-based approach.

```
lsof -c <process name> | wc -l
```

The reason I'm suggesting that is because e.g. apache on server here does the following:

```
lsof -c apache2 | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
     85 1474
     87 1625313
     87 1625314
     87 1625315
     87 1625316
     87 1625317
```

The second column being PID.

Comment: 1) That's not python. 2) you are now counting FDs from the all servers and all their threads. That's hughely more inefficient when all you need is the count for process 1474.

Comment: You didn't specify how your process operates ... hence the suggestion.  And your tag aside there's no mention of how you go about detection. 
 @GoswinvonBrederlow

Comment: "What's a good way of counting them with *python3* under *Linux*?"